# Best method to increase the chain length of allyl to butane-1,2-diol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbon-family

Best method to increase the carbon chain length of allyl. and also add 2 OH  carbon after reducing double bond give (S)-4-R-butane-1,2-diol and (R)-4-R-butane-1,2-diol .

R= Any Ak, Cb, Cy, Hy [image: increase carbon chain length]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding the convention that you should offer you ideas before receiving an answer here is a viable route.

Step 1 - hydroborate the alkene then oxidise the resulting alkylborane with N-Methyl Morphiline-N-Oxide/Tetrapropyl Ammonium Perruthenate to give the aldehyde as described [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(97)00476-0)

Step 2 - Wittig reaction with Methyltriphenylphosphonium Iodide/LDA to give the chain extended alkene

Step 3 - Syn hydroxylation of the alkene with Osmium Tetroxide/N-Methyl Morphiline-N-Oxide [details here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/upjohn-dihydroxylation.shtm).  You can buy micro-encapsulated OsO4 which is much safer to handle than the neat liquid

Comment: Is their any method which can make aldehyde together with the addition of one carbon in one step? and then we can make 1,2-diol by using asymmetric catalyst. I see it but forget this method after long time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I find that paper, also going to mention here.https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/anie.201001972#

Comment: You can also carbonylate the alkylborane to give the aldehyde, but you need the specialised equipment to do it - pressurised reaction vessel and CO gas supply - and these are not cheap.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am going to follow your procedure as you said. It's a convenient method to do.

Comment: I used your method but it's giving a mixture of two products, and also yield is only 35%. Any other method that first I convert alkene to alcohol then into aldehyde without decreasing too much yield.

Comment: i think you need to open a new question. Give full experimental details and then I'll try to answer

Comment: I take terminal olefin and make epoxide which is rarely stereoselective in the absence of a directing group. But luckily i got pure R enantiomer, now regioselective ring opening of epoxide with Li2NiBr4 in THF afforded the bromohydrin as a single regioisomer. Then i will add R groups at OH and Bromine position to get the desired product.